# How to wait for a jquery request to return a response?

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, knockout.js

I have an client web app that, when loaded, immediately makes a call to an api endpoint to see if the user is authenticated.  If not, the login stuff is displayed.  if the user is authenticated, then other information is displayed.

I don't want to display anything until this information has been returned.  My original approach was to use a synchronous call, which just seems right.  But based on responses to this question it seems that's the wrong approach:

[Synchronous JSON cross-domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437067/synchronous-json-cross-domain#comment25329966_17437067)

If so, then I need to do asynchronous and then halt until data is returned.

I'm using knockout to make the call in an activate() function like this:

```
var activate = function () {
    // get auth data
    authPayload(dataservice.getAuthPayload());
    if (!authPayload().isAuthenticated) {
        // do stuff
    } else if (authPayload().isAuthenticated === true){
        // do other stuff
    }
```

With getAuthPayload:

```
 var getAuthPayload = function () {
        var options = {
            async: false,
            url: apiEndpoint + 'api/authpayload',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json'
        };
        return $.ajax(options)
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(queryFailed);
};
```

Currently this is running synchronously though, so the `activate` function doesn't see any of the response's data since it doesn't wait for it to get back from the server.  the app currently shows a spinner until the `activate` function closes.  How can I wait on the call to `dataservice.getAuthPayload()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is you are returning the $.ajax immediately instead of using the `.done` function, this works for me:

```
    var go = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {fof: 'bar'}
    })
    .done(function(results) {
        // Code here won't execute until response received from AJAX
    })
    .fail(function(msg) {
        console.debug('Error:');
        console.debug(msg);
    })
    .always(function() {
    });
```

Comment: Just to clarify what's going on, ajax command is returning a promise which has methods like done(), fail() and always() that accept callback functions. Those supplied functions are then called when the async task finishes successfully or fails.